# A telegram bot for hinting nick name changes

Tags: chat

It does exist, at least one. I've seen it in action.

I search "telegram bot hint nickname changes" to no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several exist, [SangMata](https://t.me/SangMataInfo_bot) among them.